# move a file that matches a pattern in a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, rename

I need to move the most recent file in a directory where the filename matches a naming convention "ServicesWebApp".

Example: There is a directory with 5 files that have similar names.

```
ServicesWebApp-1005.war  created on 3/10/2016
ServicesWebApp-1004.war  created on 3/09/2016
ServicesWebApp-1003.war  created on 3/08/2016
ServicesWebApp-1002.war  created on 3/07/2016
ServicesWebApp-1001.war  created on 3/06/2016
```

I need to move the most recent one to another directory, in this example it would be.
ServicesWebApp-1005.war  created on 3/10/2016

Comment: No that is not part of the name, i just put it in as an example of the date/time that the file was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could use a oneliner if you trust your timestamps.

```
mv $(ls -tr ServicesWebApp* | tail -1) /tmp/
```

Or if you rather want to rely on the filenames.

```
mv $(ls ServicesWebApp* | sort -n | tail -1) /tmp/
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked without error. Thanks

Comment: it's good practice to use double-quotes around the `$()`.  e.g. `mv "$(ls -tr ServicesWebApp* | tail -1)" /tmp/`.  This allows the same code to be used if the requirements later change to mv a file called "some file with spaces in the name".   note that this will still fail if the filename contains a newline (`\n`) which is, unfortunately, a valid character in filenames.

Comment: with recent versions of GNU coreutils (which has added `-z` or `--zero-terminated` support to many tools), it is safe to do it with filenames containing ANY character using, e.g. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'ServicesWebApp*' -printf "%T+\t%p\0" | sort -z | cut -z -f 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one as well :

```
mv $(find . -type f -name "ServicesWebApp*" -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort -n | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1 ) /new/file/path/
```

Comment: +1 but see my comment on Thomas' answer above.    With recent GNU coreutils this can be done safely with any filename using NUL-terminated filenames and `-z` options.  e.g. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'ServicesWebApp*' -printf "%T+\t%p\0" | sort -z -n | cut -z -f 2 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /tmp/`

Answer (score 0):

```
tstamp=0
file=
for f in ServicesWebApp*
do
  y=$(stat -c "%Y" "$f")
  if [ $y -gt $tstamp ]
  then
    file="$f"
    tstamp=$y
  fi
done
echo cp "$file" /somewhere/else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a one-line execution using [command subtitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

```
$ mv $(ls -t /location/path/ServicesWebApp* | head -n1) /to/new/destination/path
```

Going forward

```
$ ls -t /location/path/ServicesWebApp* | head -n1
/location/path/ServicesWebApp-1005.war
```

So the command must be interpreted as

```
$ mv /location/path/ServicesWebApp-1005.war /to/new/destination/path
```

Comment: Hi @tachomi, do I have to do a CD into that directory in my script first or can I add the path to the command?

Comment: @Byron You can use absolute paths. I updated

Comment: im getting the following error message mv: cannot stat `ServicesWebApp-1005.war': No such file or directory.  I even added the ~ at the beggining of the destination directory. same error

Comment: @Byron I updated, if you execite manually the `ls -t /location/path/ServicesWebApp* | head -n1` what's the output?

Comment: The output is: /tmp/builds/archive/ServicesWebApp-1005.war

Comment: @Byron if you execute the entire line in the command line and not in the script, you receive the same message? Can you update your answer with what you have in your script please?