# Remove the latest modified file

Tags: command-line, files, rm, timestamps

I have created two files: 
`sample.txt` and `sample.txt`  (the second file contains some hidden characters, e.g. a space). How can I remove the latest modified file? I'm using Linux.

Comment: rm "sample.txt "

Comment: thanks for your response but i just want to delete latest file without the help of filename

Comment: What do you mean by "latest"? Most recently created?

Comment: yeah. most recently created file with same file name.

Comment: two files with the same name in one directory? oO

Comment: i have created two files manually with the same file name but the second file contains some hidden characters. i just want the command to remove the recently created file(i.e., second file)

Comment: yeah these two files are in one directory

Comment: `rm "sample.txt  "`

Comment: without the help of filename i have to delete/remove

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268990/117549

Comment: Suddenly, I realize this looks like a homework question.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`stat` is the main ingredient in this recipe: remove the `echo` if you're satisfied it's working

```
echo rm "$(stat -c "%Y:%n" * | sort -t: -n | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2-)"
```

You don't specify your platform: this is Linux and GNU tools.

Note that this doesn't work if the file name contains a newline.

Comment: `xargs` discards space (as mentioned by the OP) and also quotes and backslash (not mentioned) from the arguments it parses and passes. With *GNU* `xargs` and one value per line (as here) this can be fixed with `-d'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

The simple and reliable way to delete the latest file in the current directory is

```
zsh -c 'rm ./*(om[1])'
```

Of course, if you're running zsh, that's just

```
rm ./*(om[1])
```

Unlike other solutions proposed in this thread such as [parsing the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271361) or [of `stat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271365), this works no matter what strange characters the filename contains, even unprintable characters, even newlines.

The characters in parentheses after `*` are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). `om` means to sort by modification time (most recent first), and `[1]` means to select only the first file (after sorting).

If what you want is to get rid of a particular file, relying on the modification time is a complicated approach. Instead, type `rm` <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> and navigate through the completions that your shell offers until you hit the right file.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remove the latest file in a directory named `dir`, and the file name doesn't contain a newline character, do this:

```
rm -i -- "$(LC_CTYPE=C ls -t dir | head -1)"
```

Beware that if the file name contains unprintable characters, this may not work because `ls` may mangle the unprintable characters.

If the latest file in the directory is another directory you'll get an error such as `rm: cannot remove ‘dir2’: Is a directory`.

Comment: OP already said the filename contains special characters, which won't work with `ls`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey anything but newline (which wasn't mentioned) is fine for `ls`; the problem for space etc is unquoted command substitution, which can be fixed by quoting it. Also note this selects the last *modified* file, which is not necessarily the last *created*. And on older filesystems, it's not reliable if the files were modified/created within the same second.

Comment: why `head -1` and not `head -n1` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no (portable) direct way to do this.  But if one of the solutions in *[Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified)* (which has no accepted answer) works for you, then you would do something like

```
rm -f "$(find-sorted-list | head -n 1)"
```

where *find-sorted-list* may include a timestamp that has to be trimmed from the front of the line, e.g., with a stage involving sed.

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

for just digits and colons.

Since the question specified that the filename contains a space (among other characters), a solution using `xargs` seems to be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell function that relies on the `stat` utility; call it with an optional directory parameter (it defaults to `.`, the current directory), and it will execute an interactive `rm` of the oldest file. To throw some caution to the wind, remove the `-i` flag to `rm`. It intentionally skips directories, and so investigates only files in the given directory. In order to deal cleanly with empty directories, I added some `shopt` workarounds. This should, however, deal (as well as it can) with files that have spaces and newlines in their names.

```
function rmoldest {
  shoptnow=$(shopt -p nullglob)
  shopt -s nullglob
  tstamp=$(date +%s)
  file=
  dir=$1
  dir=${dir:-.}

  for f in "$dir"/*
  do
    if [ ! -d "$f" ]
    then
      y=$(stat -c "%Y" "$f")
      if [ $y -lt $tstamp ]
      then
        file="$f"
        tstamp=$y
      fi
    fi
  done
  $shoptnow
  if [ -n "$file" ]
  then
    /bin/rm -i "$file"
  fi
}
```

Here's a sample run (the leading `$` are my shell prompts, do not type them):

```
$ touch sample.txt; sleep 1; touch 'sample.txt '

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Jeff None 0 Mar 21 22:02 sample.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Jeff None 0 Mar 21 22:02 sample.txt

$ rmoldest
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file ‘./sample.txt’? y

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Jeff None 0 Mar 21 22:02 sample.txt

$ rmoldest
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file ‘./sample.txt ’? y

$ ls -l
total 0
```